# What not giving output

Tags: python

I have no idea why my code wont give me an output.

My Code is :

```
import random

rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

    #Write your code below this line 
    ask_user = input("What Wuould You Choose , ROCK ,  PAPER, SCICORS\n")
    ask_user_low = ask_user.lower
    if ask_user_low == 'rock':
        ask_user = rock
    if ask_user_low == 'paper':
        ask_user = paper
    if ask_user_low == 'scissors':
        ask_user = scissors

    possibe_choice = [{rock},{paper},{scissors}]
    ai_choice = random.choice(possibe_choice)



    if ai_choice == rock and  ask_user == paper:
        print(f"ai: {ai_choice} \n you:{ask_user} \n you win!")
    elif ai_choice == rock and  ask_user == scissors:
        print(f"ai: {ai_choice} \n you:{ask_user} \n you loose!")
    elif ai_choice == paper and ask_user == scissors:
        print(f"ai: {ai_choice} \n you:{ask_user} \n you win !")
    elif ai_choice == paper and  ask_user == rock:
        print(f"ai: {ai_choice} \n you:{ask_user} \n you loose !")
    elif ai_choice == scissors and  ask_user == rock:
        print(f"ai: {ai_choice} \n you:{ask_user} \n you win !")
    elif ai_choice == scissors and  ask_user == paper:
        print(f"ai: {ai_choice} \n you:{ask_user} \n you lose!")
    elif ai_choice == ask_user:
        print(f"ai:{ai_choice}\n you:{ask_user}    \n TIE!")
    else:
        print("Not A Choice Try Again :/")
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`ask_user.lower` should be `ask_user.lower()`.

`lower` is a method (which you never call), so you're literally comparing a string to the method itself.